# Update a field in the target record with the value from the source record but not overwrite the same field in the source record in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I need to update Prior YTD values from one record with the YTD values of another record but NOT overwrite the Prior YTD values of the source record in Salesforce. The same fields exist in both records.  Opp Ids are unique but I want to automate this so that when the system updates one field, it updates another.

Comment: This is hard to understand. What's your question? Making a change in one record _per se_ doesn't do anything to another record. Have you built something in Flow or Process Builder or Apex? Please [edit] to add clarity and implementation so far.

Comment: Do you really need automation? Sounds messy. I'd make lookup on opportunity called "PY Opportunity" and make "prior YTD" a formula field that pulls value from that looked up record. That way when you change prior record's YTD it'll be automatically visible on current. Bit more work setting up but you could automate something to fill in the lookup on clone maybe...

Comment: Thanks!!!  In the opportunity Object, we have 2 fields, one YTD and one Prior YTD,  Those fields exist on yearly opportunities. If the YTD field is updated on the 2020 Opp, how can I write that value to the Prior YTD field in t he 2021 Opp?  And have this done each time the YTD field on the 2020 Opp is changed/modified?